# Removing duplicate keys when concatenating maps in SCALA

Tags: scala, functional-programming, maps, concatenation

While I was studying for my exams I encountered this question. Searched on google but couldn't find an answer.

When we concatenate two maps using either the ++ operator or the Map.++() method duplicate keys will get removed. But what will happen if there are duplicate keys but different values for the keys in two maps, which one will be removed?

ex:

> Map1 contains key1->"hello"
>
> Map2 contains key1->"world"
>
> Here keys have the same name but the values are different so what will
> be the key-value pairs in the output map when Map1 and Map2 are concatenated?

Comment: Generally speaking, the behavior is non-deterministic and if you want to ensure an specific one, you should write your own function that handles that. However, I believe, most _(all current implementations?)_ will preserve the values of the last map _(in the case of two, it will be the second)_.

Comment: Thanks, @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, so according to you  the 1st key-value pair will be removed and the last one is preserved

Comment: As of today, and according to a few experiments I did, yes. But again, if this is a critical requirement, I would recommend you to write your own implementation that ensures your requirement, as I said, the behavior is left open to change, and nothing prevents the authors to do the opposite, or making it non-deterministic on a future _(however, I doubt that will happen)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to be explicit in overriding/merging logic you can do something like:

```
val map1 = Map("key1" -> "hello")
val map2 = Map("key1" -> "world")

val jointKeys = map1.keySet.intersect(map2.keySet)
val overlap = jointKeys.map(key => (key -> map2(key))).toMap // or use whatever custom override/concatenate logic instead of this lambda
val merged = overlap ++ map1.filterKeys(jointKeys) ++ map2.filterKeys(jointKeys)
```